# How to extract data from html using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following HTML code below (not complete html file but it will suffice for understanding the problem). I am trying to extract the values from the h3 element as well as the data in the p elements. For example, I'd like to have this sort of format:

```
NYC Row Restaurant Week
From April 20st through April 28th

Mother's Day at Restaurant
May 11th, 2014

A new lunch experience at Restaurant
Beginning February 5th
```

The reason I'd like to extract those values is because I want to input them into other parts of the code (i.e. a jquery accordion type buttons)

Example HTML Below

```
    <ul class="press">
                            <li>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="/about/calendar/nyc-row-restaurant-week-2">NYC Row Restaurant Week</a>                     </h3>
                    <p class="date">
                        From April 20st through April 28th                      </p>
                </li>
                                    <li>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="/about/calendar/mothers-day-at-restaurant-nyc">Mother&#039;s Day at Restaurant</a>                     </h3>
                    <p class="date">
                        May 11th, 2014                      </p>
                </li>
                                    <li>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="/about/calendar/a-new-lunch-experience-at-restaurant-4">A new lunch experience at Restaurant!</a>                      </h3>
                    <p class="date">
                        Beginning February 5th                      </p>
                </li>


                            <li>
```

My JavaScript and HTML file

```
<html>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"    
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var your_url = 'http://www.jaleo.com/about/calendar';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// jquery.xdomainajax.js  ------ from padolsey

jQuery.ajax = (function(_ajax){

var protocol = location.protocol,
    hostname = location.hostname,
    exRegex = RegExp(protocol + '//' + hostname),
    YQL = 'http' + (/^https/.test(protocol)?'s':'') +  '://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?',
    query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';

function isExternal(url) {
    return !exRegex.test(url) && /:\/\//.test(url);
}

return function(o) {

    var url = o.url;

    if ( /get/i.test(o.type) && !/json/i.test(o.dataType) && isExternal(url) ) {

        // Manipulate options so that JSONP-x request is made to YQL

        o.url = YQL;
        o.dataType = 'json';

        o.data = {
            q: query.replace(
                '{URL}',
                url + (o.data ?
                    (/\?/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + jQuery.param(o.data)
                : '')
            ),
            format: 'xml'
        };

        // Since it's a JSONP request
        // complete === success
        if (!o.success && o.complete) {
            o.success = o.complete;
            delete o.complete;
        }

        o.success = (function(_success){
            return function(data) {

                if (_success) {
                    // Fake XHR callback.
                    _success.call(this, {
                        responseText: data.results[0]
                            // YQL screws with <script>s
                            // Get rid of them
                            .replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, '')
                    }, 'success');
                }

            };
        })(o.success);

    }

    return _ajax.apply(this, arguments);

};

})(jQuery.ajax);



 $.ajax({
   url: your_url,
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {

   var result = res.responseText;
   var myHtml = $(result).find('h3').text();
   //I get stuck here and I'm not sure how to get the results in the format i specified above (in the question portion)
   alert(myHtml);

}
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `.text()`? What do you mean by "key value pairs"? It's not clear exactly what you want the extracted data to look like.

Comment: Is all that ajax and other stuff relevant to the question? Maybe simplify.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to extract the results in key value pairs" What key-value pairs are you expecting? The only possible keys would be numeric indexes.

Comment: Sorry for the "key value pair" confusion. What I really mean is I'd like to get the value of the h3 and its corresponding p value for all 3 of the elements. Actually, there will be more than just those 3, so I'd like to have some sort of way (i.e. loop) to get all of the results

Comment: If you weren't using jQuery I would suggest : var h3 = document.querySelectorAll('h3 > p' ); (http://jsfiddle.net/85EGa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extracting the text of the child elements, then recombining them as needed:

```
var arr = [];
$(result).find('li').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).find('h3 a').text();
    var dat = $(this).find('.date').text();
    arr.push(title + "<br>" + dat);
}); // arr is an array of HTML strings
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, however I only get one big string of text with all of the titles combined. I would need to separate them into different strings --> each title and its corresponding date as one string. Then the next title with its corresponding date as the next string..and so on

Comment: So what do you want in the end? an array of html strings? (Updated answer -- since I don't know exactly what `responseText` looks like, you might need to adapt it.)

Comment: I updated my expected output in my original post. I don't actually want the <br> in there. I just want the data. The reason I put the <br> was just to format it so it looks better. So in the end, I just want something like this --> NYC Row Restaurant Week
From April 20st through April 28th. I'll try your updated solution

Comment: I think your solution is the closest to working, the only issue is how can I only look at the part of <ul class="press> ... </ul> . I only want to look at the <li> elements inside of that particular <ul class="press"> because otherwise there is other <li> elements on the page that I don't care about. Thanks

Comment: Add an ID to that particular `<ul class="press">` and select the ID, or use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) to select a particular `ul.press`  out of a group.

Comment: Can you please update this in your example above? Thanks very much for your help. I'm marking your solution as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list using `each()`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: your_url,
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {

   var result = res.responseText;
   var myHtml = $(result).find('li');

    myHtml.each(function(){
        alert($(this).find("p").text());
        alert($(this).find("h3").text());
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your solution, however I get empty alert boxes. There are no errors, it's just an empty alert box.

Comment: Ok, I expected result to be like the example html you provided.